# React-Native - InputText don't lose focus

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-native project, I'm using some TextInput.
I'm having an issue a with specific use-case.

https://snack.expo.io/B1RCy4Eef

As you can see in this Snack project, i'm having an Orange Square and a TextInput.

When my InputText is focused, i'd like it to lose focus when i'm tapping on another component of my View like, for instance, the orange square.

I'd like a solution that **doesn't** requires me to add a *Keyboard.dismiss()* call to every component of my root View or my root View itself.

Thanks for your understanding && your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to add dismiss to every component, only add one full screen View handling touch and dismiss keyboard will work.here is my codes。

```
render() {
    return (<View style={styles.container} >
        <View style={{height: 300, width: 300, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Thanks for your time !
          Tap the InputText and try to lose focus while tapping on the 
          Square above
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity 
         style={{position:"absolute", 
             backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
             opacity:0, 
             width:Dimensions.get('window').width, 
             height:Dimensions.get('window').height, 
             left:0,
             top:0}} 
         onPress= {this._onClick.bind(this)}/>
       <TextInput
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          ref={(c)=>this._textInput = c}
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange}
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 50, borderWidth: 1, padding: 8 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
}

_isContainInRect(rect, point){
    return point.x >= rect.x && point.x <= rect.x + rect.width && point.y >= 
    rect.y && point.y <= rect.y + rect.height;
}

_onClick(e){
    console.log("............onclick")
    let a = e.nativeEvent;
    let point = { x: e.nativeEvent.pageX, y: e.nativeEvent.pageY };
    this._textInput.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
        let rect = { x: px, y: py, width, height }
        if (!this._isContainInRect(rect, point)) {
            console.log("will dismiss....")
            dismissKeyboard();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! A bit more explanations of the _onClick() logic would be appreciated.
But it is the accepted answer for now :)

Comment: the _onClick function handles touch on the whole screen and check if the touch is in TextInput bound. if not, dismiss the keyboard. let point = { x: e.nativeEvent.pageX, y: e.nativeEvent.pageY }; is the touch coordinate.let rect = { x: px, y: py, width, height } is the bound of TextInput. @LouisLecocq